# Autogenerate Number like 1 ,2,3,4 and so on serial no in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i'm new to mongoose, i need to generate serial number like 1, 2,3 to so on for each and every post api operation in mongoose nodejs with expressjs. please help me, how to generate the serial number in create operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in support for that. You have two options:

1. Use a library that does it for you, like https://github.com/ramiel/mongoose-sequence
2. Build your own simple logic - create a collection that has nothing but a single document with a counter inside; each time you need to perform some logic, firs query the document, increment it, save it, then get the result and use it as your next "incremented" value

p.s.
If you want to have "per document" incrementation - use `pre save` hook and include your own counter field inside.

Comment: is there any option in schema for incrementation, instead of call doing api or pre-save?

Comment: You can just install the package I've sent you and include it as a plugin. You don't need to do API calls. There's no built-in functionality for that.

Comment: yes, you are right, i have used npm package and things works perfectly. thanks for your response.

Comment: If that's the case, please either accept the answer or close the question (we try not to leave opened questions here :)). Good luck!